# Troubleshoot Google Sheets Script to Generate Form Based on Sheet Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use a Google Sheets script to generate new Google Forms based on a data inside a sheet. The code I have can create a new form with the correct title but it will not populate the form with any other information from the sheet: form description, questions, help text, etc. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

[Editable Copy of Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BUTPR8CJ45hAhAbQkiQDeHPPgnwElBIEURlCRzamgZg/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var createForm = [ {name: "Generate", functionName: "CreateFormfromSheet"}];
  ss.addMenu("Generate Test", createForm);
}

function CreateFormfromSheet() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var range = ss.getDataRange(); 
 var data = range.getValues();
 var numberRows = range.getNumRows();
 var numberColumns = range.getNumColumns();
 var firstRow = 2;
 var form = FormApp.create(data[0][1]);

 form.setDescription(data[0][2]);

 for(var i=0;i<numberRows;i++){
  var questionType = data[i][1]; 
  if (questionType==''){
     continue;
  }
  else if(questionType=='TEXT'){
   form.addTextItem()
     .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
     .setHelpText(data[i][2])
     .setRequired(true);   
  } 
  else if(questionType=='PARAGRAPH'){
   form.addParagraphTextItem()
     .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
     .setHelpText(data[i][2])
     .setRequired(true);
  }
  else if(questionType=='CHOICE'){
  var rowLength = data[i].length;
  var currentRow = firstRow+i;
  var currentRangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(currentRow,1,1,rowLength).getValues();
  var getSheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var numberOfColumnsSheet = getSheetRange.getNumColumns();
  var numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow = numberOfColumnsSheet;
  var lastColumnInRange = String.fromCharCode(64 + (numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow));
  var range_string = 'E' + currentRow + ":" + lastColumnInRange + currentRow;
  var optionsArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(range_string).getValues();
  var choicesForQuestion =[];
    for (var j=0;j<optionsArray[0].length;j++){
        choicesForQuestion.push(optionsArray[0][j]);
        }
  form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
    .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
    .setHelpText(data[i][2])
    .setChoiceValues(choicesForQuestion)
    .setRequired(true); 
  }
  else if(questionType=='CHECKBOX'){
  var rowLength = data[i].length;
  var currentRow = firstRow+i;
  var currentRangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(currentRow,1,1,rowLength).getValues();
  var getSheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var numberOfColumnsSheet = getSheetRange.getNumColumns();
  var numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow = numberOfColumnsSheet;
  var lastColumnInRange = String.fromCharCode(64 + (numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow));
  var range_string = 'E' + currentRow + ":" + lastColumnInRange + currentRow;
  var optionsArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(range_string).getValues();
  var choicesForQuestion =[];
    for (var j=0;j<optionsArray[0].length;j++){
        choicesForQuestion.push(optionsArray[0][j]);
        }
  form.addCheckboxItem()
    .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
    .setHelpText(data[i][2])
    .setChoiceValues(choicesForQuestion)
    .setRequired(true);
  }
  else if(questionType=='LIST'){
  var rowLength = data[i].length;
  var currentRow = firstRow+i;
  var currentRangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(currentRow,1,1,rowLength).getValues();
  var getSheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var numberOfColumnsSheet = getSheetRange.getNumColumns();
  var numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow = numberOfColumnsSheet;
  var lastColumnInRange = String.fromCharCode(64 + (numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow));
  var range_string = 'E' + currentRow + ":" + lastColumnInRange + currentRow;
  var optionsArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(range_string).getValues();
  var choicesForQuestion =[];
    for (var j=0;j<optionsArray[0].length;j++){
        choicesForQuestion.push(optionsArray[0][j]);
        }
  form.addListItem()
    .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
    .setHelpText(data[i][2])
    .setChoiceValues(choicesForQuestion)
    .setRequired(true);
  }
  else if(questionType=='GRID'){
  var rowLength = data[i].length;
  var currentRow = firstRow+i;
  var currentRangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(currentRow,1,1,rowLength).getValues();
  var getSheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var numberOfColumnsSheet = getSheetRange.getNumColumns();
  var numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow = numberOfColumnsSheet;
  var lastColumnInRange = String.fromCharCode(64 + (numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow));
  var range_string = 'E' + currentRow + ":" + lastColumnInRange + currentRow;
  var optionsArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(range_string).getValues();
  var rowTitles =[];
    for (var j=0;j<optionsArray[0].length;j++){
        rowTitles.push(optionsArray[0][j]);
        }
  var rowLength = data[i+1].length;
  var currentRow = firstRow+i+1;
  var currentRangeValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(currentRow,1,1,rowLength).getValues();
  var getSheetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  var numberOfColumnsSheet = getSheetRange.getNumColumns();
  var numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow = numberOfColumnsSheet;
  var lastColumnInRange = String.fromCharCode(64 + (numberOfOptionsInCurrentRow));
  var range_string = 'E' + currentRow + ":" + lastColumnInRange + currentRow;
  var optionsArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(range_string).getValues();
  var columnTitles =[];
    for (var j=0;j<optionsArray[0].length;j++){
        columnTitles.push(optionsArray[0][j]);
        }  
  form.addGridItem()
    .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
    .setHelpText(data[i][2])
    .setRows(rowTitles)
    .setColumns(columnTitles)
    .setRequired(true);
  } 
  else if(questionType=='IMAGE'){
   var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch(data[i][3]); 
   form.addImageItem()
     .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
     .setHelpText(data[i][2])
     .setImage(img);
  }
  else if(questionType=='PAGE'){
   form.addPageBreakItem()
     .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
     .setHelpText(data[i][2]);   
  } 
  else if(questionType=='SECTION'){
   form.addSectionHeaderItem()
     .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
     .setHelpText(data[i][2]);   
  }
  else if(questionType=='TIME'){
   form.addTimeItem()
     .setTitle(data[i][1]) 
     .setHelpText(data[i][2]);   
  }
  else{
    continue;
  }
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be on the indexes within the data[][] matrix.

The description is located on data[0][4], as opposed to the current value in the script as data[0][2].

Finally, in the 'for' to create a question, you are looking for the type of question in data[i][1], but it should rather be data[i][0].

I've modified the script and it should be working now.

Comment: Thank you Rivero. I am trying to improve the sheet. Now something is wrong with the way I have set the lastColumnInRange variable. It is not detecting the last empty cell in each row. It is stopping at the end of the sheet range (in this case 15 columns). So every question in the form has 15 options regardless of the number of options in the Test Generator Sheet. Here is an example (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1y8OfOo5kk8Wcfc4NuB_VLS-uzeDS4Tbyteh8gYG9abg/viewform) Any ideas?